# Shortcut for binding same command to multiple key

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings, terminal

Is there any way to map same command to multiple key without repeating mapping. Like mapping this one

```
inoremap ) <right>
inoremap " <right>
inoremap ] <right>
```

into something like this.

```
inoremap ) <or> " <or> ] <right>
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't possible unfortunately, but if it's something you tend to do often, you can write a function to do it for you:

```
function! CustomMap(commands, rhs, type)
    for l:command in a:commands
        sil!exe a:type."map ".l:command." ".a:rhs
    endfor
endfunction

call CustomMap([')', '"', ']'], '<right>', 'inore')
```